# Google Voice Dialer for Linux?

Tags: google-voice

Is there a google voice dialer that runs as a stand-alone application?  I would prefer to login through the application and not the web browser if possible.

Walter

Comment: Would a [Chrome Application Shortcut](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95710) work?

Comment: Na, I want it to be native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google developed a [desktop Google Voice app](http://lifehacker.com/5578339/a-sneak-preview-of-the-google-voice-desktop-app) based on the Gizmo5 software they acquired, but it's [likely it will never be released](http://techcrunch.com/2010/06/11/google-voice-desktop-app-launch-delayed-may-be-scrapped/) due to Google's strategy and focus on web-based apps.

There are a couple of apps that let you make google voice calls from the Desktop. The [Adobe Air utility for Google Voice](http://rstoeber.com/apps/Google_Voice_Utility.html) is one that will run on Linux as well as windows. This doesn't have a system tray icon but is the most feature-rich.

There is also the windows-only [Google Voice Notifier](http://www.daveamenta.com/2009-11/gvnotifier-net-brings-google-voice-sms-to-the-desktop/), which doesn't help you for linux. Finally there is [GoogSysTray](http://googsystray.sourceforge.net/), which is a catch-all notifier for google services that runs on Linux as well as windows. It doesn't support making calls but will let you know of voicemails and SMS.

It's possible that by using both the Air app and GoogSysTray would provide functionality equaivalent to what you're looking for.

Comment: This is the closest to what I want.  Actually, for some odd reason Ekiga finally works with Gizmo5 servers with no change in configuration.  It just started working, I wonder if gizmo5 changed something on their end.

Comment: @imotama, nice answer! I've heard about this GV desktop app which will probably never be released, and it makes me very sad. :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your question still stands anymore, but I've [written an app](http://code.google.com/p/qgvdial/) that works (in addition to others) on Linux.
Integrates with SIP through telepathy and Skype through dbus.
Call out (skype/SIP) and call back.
Integration with Google contacts.

Comment: Cool, I will have to check it out.

Comment: I just checked it out, under downloads, I only see Maemo 5, Symbian, and Windows.  Does the Maemo version work on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean some kind of software not in the cloud? I have been using google voice through my phone and its working pretty good. I am not sure if this is the kind of thing you are asking for: [google voice app for blackberry](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Mobile/thread?tid=31c15af75f15f081&hl=en) or may be [google chrome extension for google voice](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/beoddpfedeggnbomdpakbobkklaphllf)

Comment: I already have the google chrome extension, it works nicely, but I have to have a browser window open.  I want something that integrates with the OS so that I have a nice status bar icon.